# Material UI - Select - how to use the input prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

From the docs:

> An Input element; does not have to be a material-ui specific Input.

when I use Material Input it works
yet when using `<input/>` the open-arrow-icon disappear, and the selection can't be opened.

i want to use Material-UI Select, with my own custom input not materail-UI input.

**Working**

```
<Select
      
      value={value}
      onChange={_onChange}
      classes={classes}
      input={<MaterialUiInput />} //this line
    >
      {manuItems}
    </Select>
```

**Not Working**

```
<Select
      
      value={value}
      onChange={_onChange}
      classes={classes}
      input={<input />} //this line
    >
      {manuItems}
    </Select>
```

Comment: Can you please code and explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: added @GouthamJ.M

Comment: is there any specific reason why you need to use custom input ?

Comment: Could you reproduce your error in codesandbox?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito there's no error. I don't understand how to use the material-ui select component with custom input, which is not material-ui input.

Answer (score -1):

I read the source code and got to know that only if you give Material UI input then only you can get the Options of Arrow and Select Props , if you give native input then only it will be passed , you can verify it with below images, you can style Input of Material UI with Custom Style so There is not reason to use native input

**Material UI Input:**

[image]

**Native Input:**

[image]

Comment: I develop to a design-system in my company. we have input with certain logic and styles. I want to create a dropdown with this input, and use the material select. if i need to implement myself it beats the purpose of using the Material ui select.